# why boolean is returning true in mongodb for following code?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2fa66ebd77e3f5fb61b048"),
    "name" : "rohit",
    "password" : "abc123"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2fa6d3bd77e3f5fb61b049"),
    "name" : "karan",
    "password" : "kar123"
}
```

this is my mongo db collection named as credentials

now whenever I am running command

```
db.credentials.find({$and: [{'name':'rohit'},{'password':'abc12'}]}).pretty()
```

this doesn't return any result as and condition is failed

**But**

```
Boolean(db.credentials.find({$and: [{'name':'rohit'},{'password':'abc12'}]}))
```

this is always returning true.

need help to resolve this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of find in mongoDB

find() returns

- [], empty array if no results are found ***// true***
- object if there is exactly 1 result ***// true***
- [object] array of objects when many results ***// true***

secondly

db.credentials.find({$and: [{'name':'rohit'},{'password':'abc12'}]}) returns a promise which is always true in boolean (if using node js)

Thus always the Boolean value is true

A better version of the code would be (mongo shell):

```
var res = db.credentials.find({$and: [{'name':'rohit'},{'password':'abc12'}]})     
if(Array.isArray(res))
    res =[res]
Boolean(res.length)
```

Comment: i am using it in mongo shell which has nothing to do with node, if i am not wrong.

var res = await db.credentials.find({$and: [{'name':'rohit'},{'password':'abc12'}]})     

this line gives an error in mongo shell,  I need the solution for shell code not for nodejs

Comment: that is node js code. I just put that so that you can check the output.

Comment: i know its nodejs code but various functions also work in mongo shell like let,var etc.

although thnx for support.